# HTTPS Request to HTTP Drops Headers?

Tags: c#, http, iis-7, https, header

This is more for curiosity as I'm failing to find any answers or documentation for this phenomenon, but here's the scenario:

There are 2 services/applications, both hosted on IIS 7. Service 1 receives an HTTPS request from an external source (browser, fiddler, etc.) and to validate the request it needs to call service 2, so service 1 makes its own, new, separate call over HTTP to service 2. **This call has an Authorization header added to the request object.**  When service 2 receives this call, **the authentication header is gone**, as if stripped out. Thus the authentication fails, this returns to service 1 which then rejects the external call.

Does anyone have an explanation why this header, and some others from what I've seen in testing, doesn't make it through with the HTTP call? Is this a behavior of IIS, or ASP.NET, or something? If the call to service 2 was HTTPS then the headers make it through fine. I'm generating the request like so:

```
string uriendpoint = "http://service.test.com/testService.svc/authtest";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriendpoint);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var authField = MD5Hash("test:test!!2013");
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, authField.ToString());
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker of mine came across the root cause of this behavior being IIS's "URL Rewrite" module. We had it setup to do a permanent redirect of http requests to https, and this redirect is where the headers get dropped. It's a bit odd that IIS does this, but I guess I'll just try something else to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the "service 2" have code similar to "If incoming request is HTTP ignore authorization headers". It is very reasonable behavior as HTTP traffic can be very easily sniffed and replayed - so honest servers block callers from potentially unsecure behavior.

Comment: I mean... I thought about putting that into the code, since we can't successfully authenticate the call because our headers don't come through. Settled instead with just forcing https on all ends, but still doesn't explain why those headers are gone.

Comment: @Tom - "Gone" as in "I've looked at traffic coming to server 2 and it did not have headers" or "request on server 2 is not authenticated"? I strongly doubt headers are "lost", instead I expect them to be ignored.

Comment: When I debug it locally, the authentication manager that's set to the endpoints has none of the headers passed into the operationcontext object. There's also a file logger in the same place that gets triggered on this state and logs that info on remote servers, corroborating my findings locally.

Comment: @Tom - it feels you use WCF - check configuration of your "Service 2" - there is a good chance that on http there is no security configured (and I suspect you may not be able to do that).